# Building Boost in Release mode with Asserts

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, bjam

This seems to be a really hard thing to google for based on all the keywords in the question.

When building boost with bjam / b2, how do I get a fully-optimised release build but with asserts switched on?

Assuming this is possible, I'd also like to adjust the naming (using --layout=versioned) to be different from a normal release build (ie adding a -a flag to the library name). If there's no easy way I can just rename the resulting files.

Edit: should have mentioned that this is Linux (Centos 6.2)

Comment: You can specify the name of the Output File in the project properties, in linker->general for exes and librarian->general for libs. You can use references like $(ProjectName), $(OutDir), $(ConfigurationName), etc to construct the name as well. e.g $(ProjectName)-a.lib

Comment: A side remark: Assert statements sometimes depend on variables that are removed in non-debug or optimised builds - something that is not usually a problem as both asserts and debug related variables are both removed during optimised builds. If you can guarantee the existence of the variables(utilised within the assert statements) are independent of the compiler's debug/non-debug settings, having assert statements in an optimized build will work.

Comment: For the first comment, this isn't Visual Studio. As for the second, I appreciate what you're saying, but I'd be surprised if this was the case in boost, seems like release+asserts is fairly common. Debug builds can be really slow, so having a layer of asserts to catch predictable errors speeds things up a lot.